# Как добавить класс только выбранной карточке?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codepen.io/likeavenus/pen/jJQyQO?editors=0010

пример моей задуманной активности.

Я новичок в React. Пытаюсь переворачивать только ту карту, по которой кликнул, но текущая логика добавляет класс `opened` сразу всем карточкам и я понимаю почему. Вопрос в том как написать так, что бы добавлять класс только выбранной карточке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий вариант:

https://codepen.io/smolinpavel/pen/YMQQYW

```
const Test = () => (
  <div className="box">
    <TestItem/>
  </div>
);

const randomElem = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
const cards = [
  {
    id: 1,
    active: 0,
    status: 'lose',
    opened: false

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    active: 0,
    status: 'lose',
    opened: false

  },
  {
    id: 3,
    active: 0,
    status: 'lose',
    opened: false
  }
];

cards[randomElem].active = 1;
cards[randomElem].status = 'win';

class TestItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cards
  };

  openCard = id => {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    const newCards = cards.map(card => 
      card.id === id 
        ? { ...card, opened: !card.opened}
        : card
    );
    this.setState({ cards: newCards });
  }

  render() {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    const cardsArr = cards.map(({ active, id, opened, status }) => {  
      const className = `card${active ? ' active' : ''}${opened ? ' opened' : ''}`
      return (
        <div key={id} onClick={() => this.openCard(id)} className={className}>
          {status}
        </div>
      )
    });

    return(
      <>
        {cardsArr}
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Проблема вашего решения была в том, что в функции `openCard` вы присваивали общее значение `opened` - поэтому все карточки и открывались. В моём примере в обработчик `onClick` передается функция, которая изменяет значение `opened` только для той карточки, по которой произошёл клик.

Похожие примеры подробно разобраны в официальном [туториале](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), который теперь доступен и на [русском языке](https://ru.reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Если использовать [хуки](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), то можно получить ещё более элегантное решение https://codepen.io/smolinpavel/pen/yrXoXB

Comment: спасибо за ответ) сложно читать ваш код, т.к. я в es6 тоже пока слабоват)